# Solve equation with x in the base and x in the exponent

Tags: exponentiation

For Example:
$5+5x=4\cdot 1.03^x$

My Question is: Is there a mathematical way that lets me solve equation where a $x$ is in the base and in the exponent?

Comment: There is...but not very satisfying many times. Google "Lambert W-function"

Comment: @Arthur: Not really, just change variables to $x+1$ after factoring out the $5$.

Comment: You will need numerical methods or the Lambert-W-function. The newton-method applying to $f(x)=4\cdot 1.03^x-5x-5$ will probably be best.

Comment: There are $2$ solutions, one near $-0.205$ and the other near $184.194$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$5+5x=4\:c^x\qquad\text{with}\quad c=1.03$$
FIRST PART, analytic calculus (probably this is not the kind of answer expected) :

Let $\quad X=x+1 \quad\to\quad 5X=4\:c^{X-1}\quad\to\quad \frac{5c}{4}X=c^X=e^{X\ln(c)}$

$-X\ln(c)e^{-X\ln(c)}=-\frac{4\ln(c)}{5c} \quad\to\quad -X\ln(c)=W\left(-\frac{4\ln(c)}{5c} \right)$

$W$ is the Lambert's W function.
$$x=-1-\frac{1}{\ln(c)}W\left(-\frac{4\ln(c)}{5c} \right)$$
The exact result is : 
$$x=-1-\frac{1}{\ln(1.03)}W\left(-\frac{4\ln(1.03)}{5.15} \right)\simeq\begin{cases}-0.204829\\184.194\end{cases}$$
The Lambert W function is a multi valuated function. Two roots are obtained in the present case. Both are valable solutions of the equation $\quad 5+5x=4\:(1.03^x)$.

SECOND PART, approximate calculus :

Supposing that we look for a small $x$ only.

$$1.03^x=e^{x\ln(1.03)}\simeq e^{0.03x}\simeq 1+0.03x$$
$$5+5x\simeq 4(1+0.03x)$$
$$x\simeq \frac{1}{-5+0.12}\simeq -0.204918 $$
The accuracy can be increased thanks to further iterative methods (Newton-Raphson for example).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You seem to know much about Lambert's function. Is it possible to calculate both solutions for the function? Because my calculator does not have the function.

Comment: The LambertW function is implanted in some mathematicam softwares. For example WolframAlpha : http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1-1%2Fln%281.03%29LambertW%28-4ln%281.03%29%2F5.15%29 . One can find several papers : http://www.jfepperson.org/2edition-web/lambert.pdf
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042712005213

Comment: For the other branche : http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1-1%2Fln%281.03%29LambertW%28-1%2C-4ln%281.03%29%2F5.15%29

Answer (score 0):

$$5+5x=4 \cdot 1.03^x \Rightarrow 5(1+x)=1.03^x \cdot 1.03 \cdot {4\over 1.03} \Rightarrow 5(1+x)=1.03^{(1+x)} \cdot {4\over 1.03}$$
$$a=1+x$$
$$5a=1.03^a \cdot {4\over 1.03} \Rightarrow 5 \cdot {1.03\over 4}a=1.03^a \Rightarrow 1.2875a=1.03^a \Rightarrow 1.2875a \cdot 1.03^{-a}=1$$
$$z=e^{ln(z)} \Rightarrow 1.2875a \cdot e^{-a \cdot ln1.03}=1$$
$$y=-a \cdot ln1.03$$
$$1.2875a \cdot {-a \cdot ln1.03\over -a \cdot ln1.03} \cdot e^{-a \cdot ln1.03}=1$$
$$y \cdot e^y=(-a \cdot ln1.03) \cdot e^{-a \cdot ln1.03}={-ln1.03\over 1.2875}$$
Lambert-$W$ function: $y=W(-{ln1.03\over 1.2875})$.
$$a=-{1\over ln1.03} \cdot y \Rightarrow 1+x=-{1\over ln1.03} \cdot y$$
$$x=-{1\over ln1.03} \cdot y-1=-{1\over ln1.03} \cdot [W(-{ln1.03\over 1.2875})+ln1.03]$$
Result: $x=-{1\over ln1.03} \cdot [W(-{ln1.03\over 1.2875})+ln1.03]$.