# how to solve this equation using logarithms

Tags: logarithms

for the equation :
$ 3^{x^2} + 3^x = 90 $
 my solution was :
$3^{x^2} + 3  ^x = 3^{2^2} + 3^2$
so $x=2$
but i want to know if there is any solution by using logarithms ?
when using wolframAlpha th solution was $ x= -2.02356 $
or $x = 2 $
but How ?

Comment: Are you sure the problem wasn't $(3^x)^2 + 3^x = 90$?

Comment: no it is  $ 3^{x^2} $

Comment: There's no way (that I can think of) to use basic algebra to solve this. It has to be done with a calculator/computer.

Comment: @TedShifrin
it would be a lot easier if it was $(3^x)^2$ but it is
$ 3^{x^2} + 3^x = 90 $

Comment: i think so . but i wanted to know if it is possible

Comment: Then I think the only way to do it is guess, which you did.

Comment: Can you post the entire solution process you used to get at the root?

Comment: all what i am able to do is to compare the L.H.S and R.H.S of the equation  like this :
$3^{x^2} + 3  ^x = 3^{2^2} + 3^2$

Comment: You can do some algebraic work to find the solution $x=2$, like you did. I suppose numerical methods would need to be used to solve for the other solution, such as Newton's method.

Comment: You can use $3^k$ is increasing so if $0< x < 2$ the result is less than 90 and for $x > 2$ the result is greater. so there is one positive solution  And if $x < 0$ then $3^{(-x)^2} $ is increasing as $3^{-x}$ is decreasing so there is one negative solution.  YOu "bumbled" onto the positive one.

Comment: @fleablood does this mean that engines like wolframAlpha finds the negative value  by continuous calculations  ?  and gives me an Approximation ?

Answer (score 1):

If we divide both sides by $3$ first, we get $$3^{x^2-1} + 3^{x-1} = 30$$
Then, we can write it as $$(3^{x-1})^{x+1}+3^{x-1} = 3^{x-1}(3^{x-1})^{x}+3^{x-1}= 30$$
Now, if we bracket $3^{x-1}$, we get $$3^{x-1}(3^{x^2-x}+1)=30$$

From here, if there exists an integer solution, $30$ must be factorized as $3 \cdot 10$ so that $3^{x-1}$ is an integer (Notice that in other factorizations of $30$, there is no term $3^k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$). So we can try $3^{x-1} = 3 \implies x=2$ and we see that it is a solution of this equation since $3^{x^2-x}+1 = 10$ when $x=2$.

Comment: Well, we know that it is a solution of the equation if we just plug the $2$ into the original equation.

Comment: We cannot always know it this easily so I wanted to share it. This is little different from directly plugging $x=2$ with intuition because I explained why $30$ should be factorized as $3 \cdot 10$ and why should $3^{x-1} = 3$.

Comment: $(x^2-1)=(x-1)(x+1)=x(x-1)+x-1$......

Comment: thanks a lot @AsBk3397 . but do you have any idea about the second value of x " $ x= -2.02356 $ " as wolframAlpha solved the equation ?

Comment: I tried to find the other value but could not find it, sorry :/

Comment: never mind .  i tried a lot to find the other value but i couldn't too

Comment: @HelloWorld Try searching the Lambert-W function. You can use it to solve problems like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2566003/solve-equation-with-x-in-the-base-and-x-in-the-exponent/2566236#2566236), but I'm not sure if you can express it in this way. Otherwise, you can use Newton's method to approximate the other root.

Comment: thanks . i'll search them

Comment: @TobyMak. No hope with Lambert, alas !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I expected this - I don't think you can reduce it to the form with the term $3^{x^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function
$$f(x)=3^{x^2}+3^x-k$$ and its derivatives
$$f'(x)=2\ 3^{x^2} x \log (3)+3^x \log (3)$$
$$f''(x)=4\ 3^{x^2} x^2 \log ^2(3)+2\ 3^{x^2} \log (3)+3^x \log ^2(3)$$ Since $3>e$, the second derivative is always positive.

On the other side $f(0)=2-k$; so, as soon as $k>2$, there will be two roots to equation $f(x)=0$.

If you consider large values of $k$, the dominant term is $3^{x^2}$ and then the roots of $3^{x^2}=k$ are given by $$x_{1,2}=\pm \frac{\sqrt{\log (k)}}{\sqrt{\log (3)}}$$ If $k=90$, this gives $x_{1,2}=\pm 2.02383$.

By inspection, you notice that $x=2$ is a root of the equation. But $f(-2)= -\frac{80}{9}$. Then, the second root is something like $x=-2+\epsilon$. So, consider now $$f(-2+ \epsilon)=3^{(\epsilon -2)^2}+3^{\epsilon -2}-90$$ and develop as a Taylor series built around $\epsilon=0$; this will give
$$f(-2+ \epsilon)=-\frac{80}{9}-\frac{2915}{9} \epsilon  \log (3)+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$ Neglecting the higher order terms, this gives
$$\epsilon =-\frac{16}{583 \log (3)}\approx -0.0249808$$ 
We could continue the expansion to $O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$ and get 
$$f(-2+ \epsilon)=-\frac{80}{9}-\frac{2915}{9} \epsilon  \log (3)+\epsilon ^2 \left(\frac{11665 \log
   ^2(3)}{18}+81 \log (3)\right)+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$ SOlving the nasty quadratic will give $\epsilon \approx -0.0236155$ and you see that we become to be very close to the result Wolfram Alpha gave.

For sure, we can use Newton method for any accuracy starting with $x_0=-2$ and get the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & \color{red}{-2.0}000000000000000000 \\
 1 &  \color{red}{-2.02}49808364082837021 \\
 2 &  \color{red}{-2.02356}80473456910369 \\
 3 &  \color{red}{-2.023563090}2293065747 \\
 4 &  \color{red}{-2.0235630901685831789}
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.

Better then with Taylor series, we could use Padé approximants and the simplest would be
$$f(-2+ \epsilon)=-\frac{\frac{80}{9}+\frac{  (11664+1792765 \log (3))}{5247}\epsilon} {1+ \frac{ (1458+11665 \log (3))}{5830}\epsilon }$$ giving, as an approximation $$\epsilon=-\frac{46640}{11664+1792765 \log (3)}\approx -0.0235411$$

Comment: If you consider large values of $k$, the dominant term is $3^{x^2}$ and then the roots of $3^{x^2}=k$ are given by $$x_{1,2}=\pm \frac{\sqrt{\log (k)}}{\sqrt{\log (3)}}$$ If $k=90$, this gives $x_{1,2}=\pm 2.02383$. 
@ClaudeLeibovici please can you explain this more .
and why the positive value isn't accurate as the negative value?

Comment: @HelloWorld. Compare $3^{x^2}$ to $3^x$ as soon as $|x]>1$. It is just an approximation : the function is not symmetric.

Comment: i mean that can i apply the method of getting the negative value in getting the positive one to get an approximation that approaches 2 Like $f(2+ \epsilon)$ and so on ?

Comment: And does it have comlplex roots ?

Comment: @HelloWorld. You asked *why the positive value isn't accurate as the negative value?*. Consider the two terms $3^{x^2}$ and $3^x$ : for $x=2$, they are in a ratio of $9:1$ but for $x=-2$ they are in a ratio of $729:1$